# MySQL optimizing LEFT JOIN with IN clause and many IDs

Tags: mysql, join

I've got 2 tables: `item` and `status`.

For each `item` I need to aggregate data from `status` table using different conditions, fields: `ingredientId`, `status`, `exemptionIds`, hence need to do the `left join` multiple times.

I've got the performance problem, it takes around 7.5s to process 500 rows on modern CPU and SSD drive.

What's weird, if I comment out last JOIN, it takes around 1,2s, if comment out last 2 JOINs, it takes around 0.7s. I would expect that more JOINs would grow time linearly, it's not the case as far I am concerned;
I actually need to add more JOINs, this would cause massive problem.

`DESCRIBE` confirms that the `PRIMARY` (which is compound `docId`, `ingredientId` index, gets used)

```
 # id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '500', '100.00', 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'aaa_psn', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'aaa_psu', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'aaa_psu2', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'aaa_pse', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'bbb_psn', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'bbb_psu', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'bbb_psu2', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'bbb_pse', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'i.docId', '139', '100.00', 'Using where'
'2', 'DERIVED', 'i', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2378132', '100.00', NULL
```

Any ideas how to improve it? Better ways of querying it given this data model? Or perhaps data model changes needed?

`status` table has around 91.2M rows, `item` table has around 2.4M rows.
Each `item` has up to-100 entries in `status` table.

Here is the query:

```
select i.*
,coalesce(
    if (count(aaa_sn.docId) > 0, 'no', null),
    if (count(aaa_su.docId) > 0, 'unknown', null),
    if (count(aaa_su2.docId) < 6, 'unknown', null),
    if (count(aaa_se.docId) > 0, 'exempt', null),
    'yes'
) as aaaCheck
,coalesce(
    if (count(bbb_sn.docId) > 0, 'no', null),
    if (count(bbb_su.docId) > 0, 'unknown', null),
    if (count(bbb_su2.docId) < 24, 'unknown', null),
    if (count(bbb_se.docId) > 0, 'exempt', null),
    'yes'
) as bbbCheck

from (
    select i.id, i.docId from item i limit 100
) i

left join status aaa_sn on aaa_sn.docId = i.docId and aaa_sn.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
and (aaa_sn.status = 'no' OR (aaa_sn.status = 'exempt' and aaa_sn.exemptionIds NOT IN (29,38,46,162,167,179,180,182,190,191,192,194,202,206,216,234,163,215,216,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,149,150,179,182,183,205,220,222,229,230,11,12,23,29,33,37,39,40,41,42,45,151,152,153,154,155,158,159,164,166,167,171,172,178,179,180,181,182,184,185,186,187,188,189,192,193,194,195,196,197,199,200,201,203,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,216,217,218,219,221,223,224,225,226,227,228)))

left join status aaa_su on aaa_su.docId = i.docId and aaa_su.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) and aaa_su.status = 'unknown'

left join status aaa_su2 on aaa_su2.docId = i.docId and aaa_su2.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)

left join status aaa_se on aaa_se.docId = i.docId and aaa_se.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
and aaa_se.status = 'exempt' and aaa_se.exemptionIds IN (29,38,46,162,167,179,180,182,190,191,192,194,202,206,216,234,163,215,216,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,149,150,179,182,183,205,220,222,229,230,11,12,23,29,33,37,39,40,41,42,45,151,152,153,154,155,158,159,164,166,167,171,172,178,179,180,181,182,184,185,186,187,188,189,192,193,194,195,196,197,199,200,201,203,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,216,217,218,219,221,223,224,225,226,227,228)



left join status bbb_sn on bbb_sn.docId = i.docId and bbb_sn.ingredientId IN (19,22,23,25,27,28,29,30,31,33,35,38,43,44,45,60,115,163,164,192,324,325,366,367)
and (bbb_sn.status = 'no' OR (bbb_sn.status = 'exempt' and bbb_sn.exemptionIds NOT IN (48,235,47,239,235,48,48,239,235,235,238,236,237,239)))

left join status bbb_su on bbb_su.docId = i.docId and bbb_su.ingredientId IN (19,22,23,25,27,28,29,30,31,33,35,38,43,44,45,60,115,163,164,192,324,325,366,367) and bbb_su.status = 'unknown'

left join status bbb_su2 on bbb_su2.docId = i.docId and bbb_su2.ingredientId IN (19,22,23,25,27,28,29,30,31,33,35,38,43,44,45,60,115,163,164,192,324,325,366,367)

left join status bbb_se on bbb_se.docId = i.docId and bbb_se.ingredientId IN (19,22,23,25,27,28,29,30,31,33,35,38,43,44,45,60,115,163,164,192,324,325,366,367)
and bbb_se.status = 'exempt' and bbb_se.exemptionIds IN (48,235,47,239,235,48,48,239,235,235,238,236,237,239)
group by i.id
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but this looks a little clunky. I'd be tempted to see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and start over.

Comment: aggregate functions with no group by... the query returns a single row... . looks suspiciously like the query isn't doing what we intended it to do. the multiple joins to status table look unwarranted; seems like we could handle that in a single join with conditional aggregation.

Comment: @spencer7593 My mistake, didn't include the `group by i.id` at the end. This means I need to get the `count` for each `item`.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for that, I will spend some time in the evening and try to provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the query in the question is going to be generating a semi-Cartesian (semi-cross) product... matching rows from `status` with other rows from `status`, potentially inflating the counts.

I suspect that we only need to join to `status` table once, matching on `docId`, and then we can run the rows through some conditional tests in expressions in the SELECT list.

As a simplified example of this approach (without introducing aggregation yet, consider:

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.docid

     , s.ingredientId
     , s.status
     , s.exemptionId

     , IF( s.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) AND s.status = 'unknown' ,1,0) AS aaa_su

     , IF( s.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)                          ,1,0) AS aaa_su2

  FROM ( SELECT j.id
              , j.docid
           FROM item j
          ORDER BY j.docid, j.id
          LIMIT 100
       ) i
  LEFT
  JOIN status s
    ON s.docid = i.docid
 ORDER BY i.id, i.docid
```

For every "matching" row from `status`, the `IF()` function is evaluated. The first expression is evaluated as a boolean; if its TRUE, the function returns the second expression, else it returns the third expression.

I've included only two of the simpler checks in this query; I've omitted the more complex expressions, just so we can demonstrate how this works. (We can extend this pattern to add additional `IF()` expressions in the SELECT list that do additional checks.

I've also included some columns from `s` that are checked in the conditions, so we can verify that we're getting 1 and 0 as we expect. (One the more complex conditions, especially using AND and OR this will help up us verify that the checks are doing what we intend.

---

The next step is to add a `GROUP BY` clause, and wrap those `IF()` expressions in aggregate functions like 'SUM()`.

Having `1` and `0` is convenient if we want to use `SUM()` to "count" rows.

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.docid

     , SUM(IF( s.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) AND s.status = 'unknown' ,1,0)) AS cnt_aaa_su

     , SUM(IF( s.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)                          ,1,0)) AS cnt_aaa_su2

  FROM ( SELECT j.id
              , j.docid
           FROM item j
          ORDER BY j.docid, j.id
          LIMIT 100
       ) i
  LEFT
  JOIN status s
    ON s.docid = i.docid
 GROUP BY i.id, i.docid
```

If we want to use `COUNT()` in place of `SUM()`, we can return any non-NULL value as the second argument, and need to return a NULL as the third argument, for example:

```
     , COUNT(IF( s.ingredientId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) ,'x',NULL) AS aaa_su2
```